# Chrome: how to remove url from autocomplete list

Tags: google-chrome

For each project that i work on, I hit certain websites often.

When i'm done with that project, i would like those website URLs to not show up in my autocomplete any longer.

How do i do this on google chrome with a mac?

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This does the trick for me:

MAC:

```
Shift + fn + Delete
```

PC:

```
Shift + Delete
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to remove it from
`C:\Users\$USER%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Bookmarks`
which is a plain-text file.

Many of the other, bigger files are sqlite3 databases..